# WordPress Fatal Errors

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I need some help please. I have a WP theme (custom) its a old site deved years ago, im upgrading everything and Im getting some errors I need assistance with,

**First Error**

> WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '' at line 1 for query SELECT name FROM
>   wdir_terms WHERE term_id= made by require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, inherit_template,
>   include('/themes/xxxxxx/archives/archive-6.php'),
>   _get_category_name_by_ID
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function
>   custom_permalinks_original_post_link() in
>   /wp-content/themes/xxxxxx/archives/archive-6.php on line 253

**Section of code from archive-6.php**

```
                    <p class="quickquotetext"><strong>Quick Quotes</strong>: <a href="#" class="quoteform">Click here</a> to email the "<? echo single_cat_title(); ?>" service providers in <?php echo _get_category_name_by_ID($_GET['cat']); ?></p>

                <?php } else { // this is the normal post loop?>

                    <? global $wp_query; global $post; query_posts(array_merge(array('posts_per_page' => '-1', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'),$wp_query->query)); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                    custom_permalinks_original_post_link(get_the_ID());                 

                        ob_start();
                        the_attached_image('img_size=full&img_tag=false');
                        $provider_logo = ob_get_clean();
                        if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            $provider_logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' );
                            $provider_logo = $provider_logo[0];
                        } 

                    ?>
```

**Second Error**

Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/xxx/wp-content/plugins/category-icons/category_icons.php(1048): wpdb->prepare('CREATE TABLE IF...')
#1 /home/xxx/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): ig_caticons_install('')
#2 /home/xxx/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#3 /home/xxx/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#4 /home/xxx/wp-settings.php(450): do_action('init')
#5 /home/xxx/wp-config.php(87): require_once('/home/ in /home/xxx/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1222
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /home/xxx/wp-content/plugins/category-icons/category_icons.php on line 1048 and defined in /home/xxx/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1222
```

Comment: hmm the errors are explicit enough, just need to fix them. Redoing some of the code is probably in order for example you should never use `query_posts`

Comment: Thanks Mark, Im more of a IT guy vs Dev. I have fixed most already, bar these.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages are pretty straightforward.

First error:

`custom_permalinks_original_post_link()` is not defined. It might be one defined by a plugin called "Custom Permalinks". See https://github.com/GSA/custom-permalinks/blob/master/custom-permalinks.php.

If you need that functionality, install/activate the plugin or refactor your code.

Second error:

It's clear that the `category-icons` plugin is doing something wrong and not calling `wpdb::prepare()` properly. You should ask the developer to update their plugin or find an alternative. Perhaps [WP Term Icons](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-term-icons/) is such an alternative.